# Android: 2 Listviews in NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, listview, navigation-drawer

I've done a `Navigation Drawer` in my app and the works ok. But I'm trying to put another `Listview` below the above but I can not get the new display on the screen. I have put the `Navigation Drawer` in `BaseActivity` class. What can be the error? This is my code:

**XML**

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<LinearLayout
...

</LinearLayout>


 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:orientation="vertical">


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
    style="@style/scrollbar"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/negro"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp" />


<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listview_drawer2"
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@color/negro"
    android:dividerHeight="1dp"
    android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
    style="@style/scrollbar"/>
 </LinearLayout>


</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

**BASEACTIVITY**

```
private void cargarDrawerLayout(Bundle b) {

    mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

    textosMenuLateral = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_drawer);
    textosMenuLateral2 = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.titulos_drawer2);

    iconosMenuLateral = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_drawer);

    iconosMenuLateral2 = getResources()
            .obtainTypedArray(R.array.iconos_drawer2);

    mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer);
    mDrawerList2 = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview_drawer2);

    View header = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.drawer_header, null);
    mDrawerList.addHeaderView(header);
    mDrawerList2.addHeaderView(header);

    int[] colores = {0, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0};
    mDrawerList.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colores));
    mDrawerList.setDividerHeight(4);

    mDrawerList2.setDivider(new GradientDrawable(Orientation.RIGHT_LEFT, colores));
    mDrawerList2.setDividerHeight(4);

    navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();
    navDrawerItems2 = new ArrayList<DrawerItem>();

    navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[0], iconosMenuLateral.getResourceId(0, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[1], iconosMenuLateral.getResourceId(1, -1)));
    navDrawerItems.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral[2], iconosMenuLateral.getResourceId(2, -1)));

    navDrawerItems2.add(new DrawerItem(textosMenuLateral2[0], iconosMenuLateral2.getResourceId(0, -1)));

    iconosMenuLateral.recycle();
    iconosMenuLateral2.recycle();

    mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());
    mDrawerList2.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener2());

    adapter = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems,
            perfilObj.getColor(),
            pos);
    mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

    adapter2 = new DrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
            navDrawerItems2,
            perfilObj.getColor(),
            pos2);
    mDrawerList2.setAdapter(adapter2);

    mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, 
            mDrawerLayout,
            R.drawable.icono_drawer, 
            R.string.app_name,
            R.string.app_name
    ) {
        public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {

            getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        } 

        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {

            getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);

            invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    };
    mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);    

        opcionesPanelLateral(position);
    }
}

private class SlideMenuClickListener2 implements ListView.OnItemClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {

        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);
        textView.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);    

        opcionesPanelLateral2(position);
    }
}

private void opcionesPanelLateral(int position) {

    Intent i;

    switch (position - 1) {
        case 0:


        case 1:


        case 2:


        case 3:

            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    mDrawerList.setItemChecked(pos, true);
    mDrawerList.setSelection(pos);
        setTitle(textosMenuLateral[pos]);

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
}

private void opcionesPanelLateral2(int position) {

    Intent i;

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }

    mDrawerList2.setItemChecked(pos, true);
    mDrawerList2.setSelection(pos);

    mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList2);
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to have 2 listviews in the first place? Can't you make a custom one to fit the content you need in a single one?

Comment: I think you want to display the two listviews in a single layout and drawer

Comment: because I think that is the easiest way to get headers

Comment: @Charlie What do you mean by headers? Just a string? As I mentioned, a custom listview can contain all the data you can fit in it, unless I am understanding it wrong.

Comment: yes, a string with a title

Comment: I want title - listview - title - listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried adding layout weight to your ListViews? A ListView will naturally match it's parent's size.
[Layout Weight](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/linear.html#Weight) I hope it helps.

```
<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
style="@style/scrollbar"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/negro"
android:dividerHeight="1dp" 
android:layout_weight="1"/>

<ListView
android:id="@+id/listview_drawer2"
android:layout_width="250dp"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="start"
android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
android:divider="@color/negro"
android:dividerHeight="1dp"
android:background="@color/grisTransparente"
style="@style/scrollbar"
android:layout_weight="1"/>
```